# How to bind low child levels to WPF TreeView by Xpath?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml

I have the following XML document.

```
  <SequenceView>
          <ExtensionData />
          <Changed>2011-09-05T10:00:00</Changed>
          <Color>255,255,0</Color>
          <DownloadbleContentItems>
            <EventFramePluginContentItemView>
              <ExtensionData />
              <ClientContentItemElements>
                <ClientContentItemElementView>
                  <ExtensionData />
                  <ID>bacd590c-e4fb-47f5-9f8e-141312f93ba0</ID>
                  <Name>URL</Name>
```

I just want to bind it to WPF TreeView

```
 <XmlDataProvider x:Key="data" Source="Data.xml">
      </XmlDataProvider>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="dt" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=SequenceList}">
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <r:TreeListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource data},XPath=/Sequences/SequenceList/SequenceView}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dt}">
      <r:TreeListView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Changed" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=Changed}" Width="150" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Color" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=Color}" Width="150" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="DownloadbleContentItems" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=DownloadbleContentItems}" Width="150">
                    // How to implemet the next Level ?
                </GridViewColumn>
            </r:TreeListView.Columns>
    </r:TreeListView>
```

What I don't know is how I can show up the next level of the XML?

I mean for: **EventFramePluginContentItemView**
and also for: **ClientContentItemElements**

Thank you!

P.S. I used this project like a sample http://windowsclient.net/blogs/ricciolocristian/archive/2008/03/22/a-complete-wpf-treelistview-control.aspx

Comment: do the XML objects represent .NET objects?

Comment: @jberger. Well... It could be deserialized like the .NET objects as well.

Comment: i mean, for example, is there an assembly which defines a class called `SequenceView` which creates the XML and which you can access?

Comment: @jberger. Yes, there is.

Comment: in that case, you may want to consider looking into `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and how to use it with a `TreeView`